# Does a file take longer to be retrieved from a domain to a subdomain or from a subdomain to itself?

Tags: mobile, web, mobile-website

I have a website and its mobile version (m.mydomainname.com), the problem is that Im in a bit of a dilemma with the mobile website. t has dependencies files like the javascripts, phps, etc. Im not sure if I should get these files from the main domain website or from their own folder. I do know that it would be easier to update them if they are only located in one folder, but I dont know if it will be reducing its speed or not. So the question basically is will it reduce its speed or not?

Answer (score 0):

I see no reasons (apart from some very esoteric ones) why putting static files in different folders should affect the speed of access, hence I'd say the answer to your question is almost certainly *no*.

However, you can always simply try both options and measure the difference in throughput. If you find any, I'd be interested to hear about it.